# Currency conversion problem with no arbitrage

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have list of currencies and a table of exchange rates. Given 1 unit of some currency I need to find the list of exchange transactions to get the maximum amount of  each other currencies. I know that there exist no cycles that allow me to get arbitrarily rich via arbitrage.

I converted this problem to a graph problem. Each currency is a vertex and the possible exchange transactions are the edges. The weight of edges is minus the log of the exchange rate so the problem is converted to a shortest path problem (minimum of the minus of sum of logs is like maximizing the multiplications).Now I perform Belman-Ford and find the best path from my source to any vertex (currency). The run time is O(n^3)

My question is there a better and faster algorithm ?

Thanks!

Ron

Comment: Are rates symmetrical, rate between A and B to be equal 1/rate between B and A?

Comment: No this is not required

Comment: That was a trick question :-) If rates are symmetrical, than all rates have to agree (A to C is same as A to B and B to C), and chain of changes would not matter. It seems to me that shortest paths is the way. It would be good to transform problem somehow so that Dijkstra's can be used.